# « Température de consigne » ou « Consigne de température »

Tags: usage

La question se pose dans le cadre de la rédaction d'une Spécification Logicielle. Je me demande quelle formule est correcte pour désigner la valeur de la température saisie par l'opérateur.

> L'opérateur peut valider la boite de dialogue après avoir renseigné la consigne de température.

Une remarque m'a été faite à propos de la formulation, arguant que la forme correcte est **température de consigne**.

La formulation de l'exigence peut-être changée, mais j'aimerai savoir si les deux formulations sont correctes et si les deux formules ont la même signification ?

La littérature est assez pauvre à ce sujet:

- [consigne sur CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consigne)
- [consigne sur CNRTL Académie 9ème édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/consigne)
- [consigne sur le Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/consigne)
- [Consigne sur Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consigne)

Comment: Un peu plus de contexte serait le bienvenu ! Le premier semble bien plus étrange que l'autre… cela dit, c'est peut-être un renseignement sur l'humeur avec laquelle la consigne a été formulée…

Comment: À la lointaine époque où j'étudiais l'électronique, pour autant que je me souvienne j'ai toujours vu _"température de consigne"_ dans les documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il y a une nuance entre les deux.

La *consigne de température* a un sens plus large et peut être par exemple un intervalle de température possible, une série temporelle (16 degré la nuit, 20 degré la journée), quelque chose d'algorithmique (5 degré de moins que la température extérieure tant que celle-ci dépasse les 25 degrés, 20 degré sinon), ...

La *température de consigne* est la température à obtenir.

Si l'opérateur doit renseigner un nombre, j'utiliserais *température de consigne*, s'il a plus de choix, *consigne de température*.

Answer (score 5):

La **température de consigne** est la valeur de cette température, valeur stipulée par la consigne.

La **consigne de température** est la chose (un papier, l'expression, le règlement...) qui porte et stipule cette température.

On dira, par exemple *Quelle est la température de consigne ?*, et *Où est la consigne de température ?*

Tout cela, à mon avis de mon opinion.

Comment: Il s'atteste, l'avis de ton opinion, où bien il est aussi ton produit de ton fantasme, à ton avis, et vice et versa ?

Answer (score 4):

IL s'agit d'une spécification logicielle, et visiblement personne ici n'est d'accord sur le sens exacte des deux possibilités. Peut-être faudrait-il écrire tout cela différemment, pour lever toute ambiguïté ?

> L'opérateur peut valider la boite de dialogue après avoir saisi
>   la température souhaitée pour la cuisson du gloubi-boulga.

Comment: En tant qu'utilisateur final, la formulation est parfaitement compréhensible, et correspond au besoin de simplification des formules administratives.
Formule pour le manuel utilisateur.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne comprends pas ton commentaire car je ne comprends pas pourquoi tu parles de formules administratives et de manuel utilisateur.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que ce qui doit être expliqué est :

> L'opérateur peut valider la boite de dialogue après avoir consigné la température.

("B.− [Le compl. désigne une parole, un fait] Mettre par écrit, mentionner, inscrire, noter, spécialement dans une pièce officielle." CNRTL)

La formulation originale est correcte, si l'opérateur doit remplir dans la boîte de dialogue, une température qu'on lui a demandé de remplir. Il a reçu la consigne de mettre cette température.

Comment: Formule pour le testeur du four ou pour le technicien de maintenance.